# How to pass ModelMap from one controller to other in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to pass one `ModelMap` object from one controller to another one, but the problem is
**1.** one controller (say `/upload`) has been assigned to `POST` method i.e. `@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)`.
**2.** another controller (say `/display`) has been assigned to `GET` method i.e.
`@RequestMapping(value="/display", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Flow of calling the contoller is from `/upload` to `/display/`. I mean after uploading the files I am redirecting it to `/display` controller. But as expected it give `405` error i.e. **Method Not Supported Error**. If both would have assigned to any one method i.e. either `RequestMethod.POST` or `RequestMethod.GET` so it would have been easier for me to pass the ModelMap object, by using **forward** in return statement.

So is there any approach so that I can fulfill my purpose. Passing object or value from Post to GET or vice versa. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**
Since the second method supports get request, why not use querystring  like

```
/display?queryparam1=Hello&queryparam2=world
```

and you can get these values, using request object or QueryParam or PathParam

**Second approach** would be to put the objects in session under some pre-defined keys. And when the control falls on the second controller, the values from session can be fetched.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, but would it be a correct approach ? I mean `/displayprofiles` controller is not going to be called with `queryParam` always. (sorry since I am a newbie in this case)

Comment: **You can easily handle those with null-handling if-else blocks.** Also if /display is already wired in your app, what is the HTTP request being send to server, consider pasting a sample.

Comment: Second Approach seems to be much handy... **Gracias**